# Joomla 404 error in Admin Panel

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I am having a strange thing happening to my Joomla site. I am unable to save anything in the Admin Panel. For instance, if I go to "Global Settings" and make any changes (eg site name or even email) and click on Save, I get a 404 Error:

> The requested page can't be found.
>
> Error: 404 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: jgive, html, jgiveView

I am using Joomla 3.4 (latest version). Please see the screenshot attached. Is anyone getting any similar error and any idea how to solve this? I have `.htaccess` enabled in my backend, with `SEF Urls` turned on. This seems to be happening randomly because the site has been working just fine and suddenly started this behaviour.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Screenshot of 404 Error]

Comment: 3.3.4 the latest version? We're now using Joomla 3.4 ;)

Comment: Disable the jGive extension from #__extensions table and let me know if it not working afterwards.

Comment: It might have been a cache issue. I cleared the cache and I don't see the error anymore. I will monitor its working for the next days and see if anything happens again.